# New Virtualhosts load default site since Apache/Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, webmin, virtualmin

I upgraded our web server from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04, which also upgraded Apache from 2.2 to 2.4.

The upgrade was successful and all existing virtualhosts are running great.

I created a new site yesterday and noticed that it was loading the default host instead of the one it should. I checked the .conf file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` and it does look a little different than the other ones.

I understand that Apache 2.4 has some changes like "Require all granted" which shows in the new .conf file alongside the previous "allow from all". I tried commenting it out but that didn't do anything.

I guess I could try backing up this file and copying over an existing working .conf file and just modify the paths to see if that works - but having to do this for every new site I add in the future is not a solution.

Does anyone experience this during their upgrade process?

**--- UPDATE ---**

I looked again at the conf file and I noticed that all my other working conf files have 2 distinct differences:

- They list the IP next to the port  `< VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80 >`, the broken one just had an asterisk *
- They duplicate the `< VirtualHost >`, one for port 80, another for port 443

So I added the IP in the broken file in the `<VirtualHost...>` and duplicated the settings for port 443, restarted apache, and the site worked.

So now it comes down to where in the Virtualmin/Webmin settings would I make adjustments to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating, first option is which IP you want to bind you domain to. That is very IP you have defined against your domain DNS.

[image]

But that is only needed if you have bounded IP with port in your conf file.

By default its `*:80`. So no need to bind.